# Divide cell with delimiter given empty cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to clean a data frame with empty rows by separating the values from one column. My dataframe currently looks like this:

```
     id_number              section 
0    00000 & A                  NaN
1    01000                        B
2    01001                        C
3    01003 & D                  NaN
4    01005 & E                  NaN
```

and i need the end result to look like this:

```
     id_number              section 
0    00000                        A
1    01000                        B
2    01001                        C
3    01003                        D
4    01005                        E
```

my code so far is

```
import pandas   
df[['id_number','section']] = df.id_number.str.split(" & ",expand=True,)
```

but it returns "None" for the the cells with sections already:

```
     id_number              section 
0    00000                        A
1    01000                     None
2    01001                     None
3    01003                        D
4    01005                        E
```

Would anyone know how to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: I don't have access to python right now so can't check this so won't put it as an answer but you need to not overwrite the existing section column. Instead save it as a temp column and then coalesce the 2.


`df[['id_number','section_T']] = df.id_number.str.split(" & ",expand=True)`


`df.section = df.section.combine_first(df.section_T)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have done is also fine, just assign the section after splitting to a new column temporarily, then just backfill the previous section and new section columns, then assign it to the section.

```py
df[['id_number','NewSection']]= df.id_number.str.split(" & ",expand=True)
df['section'] = df[['section', 'NewSection']].bfill(axis=1)['section']
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
  id_number section
0     00000       A
1     01000       B
2     01001       C
3     01003       D
4     01005       E
```

**EDIT:** Steps break out:
The given dataframe (df):

```py
   id_number section
0  00000 & A     NaN
1      01000       B
2      01001       C
3  01003 & D     NaN
4  01005 & E     NaN
```

Do the same thing that you are doing, i.e. split on `&` with `expand=True`, and assign them to `id_number`, and a new column `NewSection`.

```py
df[['id_number','NewSection']]= df.id_number.str.split(" & ",expand=True)

  id_number section NewSection
0     00000     NaN          A
1     01000       B       None
2     01001       C       None
3     01003     NaN          D
4     01005     NaN          E
```

Now take the columns `section`, and `NewSection` and backfill them on `axis=1`, so that the `NaN` values in section column get replaced by the value at `NewSection` at the given index. Then take the `section` column and assign it to the `section` of the dataframe

```py
df[['section', 'NewSection']].bfill(axis=1)
  section NewSection
0       A          A
1       B       None
2       C       None
3       D          D
4       E          E

df['section'] = df[['section', 'NewSection']].bfill(axis=1)['section']
```

Now, section will have the values with `NaN` replaced from `NewSection` for corresponding index:

```py
  id_number section NewSection
0     00000       A          A
1     01000       B       None
2     01001       C       None
3     01003       D          D
4     01005       E          E
```

Now, take only the `id_number`, and `section` columns.

Comment: Hi! When I tried this, it seemed to be returning the section column with empty values and the NewSection column with the other sections and "None" instead of the two section columns combined.

Comment: Check the code properly, it is working fine, I tested it and added it as an answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for the breakdown process! It is working perfectly now!

Answer (score 2):

Here is my suggestion:

```
df.loc[df.id_number.str.contains(' & '),'section'] = df.loc[df.id_number.str.contains(' & '),'id_number'].apply(lambda x: x.split(' & ')[1])

df.loc[df.id_number.str.contains(' & '),'id_number'] = df.loc[df.id_number.str.contains(' & '),'id_number'].apply(lambda x: x.split(' & ')[0])

>>> print(df)
  id_number section
0     00000       A
1     01000       B
2     01001       C
3     01003       D
4     01005       E
```

Comment: Happy to help :)
Please accept some of the answers, so that question will be removed from "unanswered" queue

Answer (score 1):

Heres my suggestion:

```
import re

df['id_number'] = df['id_number'].astype(str)
df.loc[df['section'].isna(), 'section'] = df['id_number'].apply(lambda x: re.sub('\d+\s\&', '', x))
df['id_number'] = df['id_number'].str.replace('\s\&\D+', '')
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for this! Although, when I tried it out, it removed the sections from the id_number column completely :(

Comment: Hey, i have tried this script in shared data it worked great, if you can share more sample to identify the error.

Comment: Hi! Sorry, there was an error on my part! Thank you so much for the help!